# Running total with maximum limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, cumulative-sum

I have a simple question but its kinda difficult for me to solve it.
I would like to have sum up a specific column till it reached a limit and resets it self. (SQL 2012)

Lets say the limit is 50

```
 - List item
 - Value    Total
 - 10        10
 - 20        30
 - 30        60
 - 40        50   (60-limit) + the current row value
 - 2         2
 - 3         5
 - 10        15
 - 25        40
 - 15        55
 - 5         10 (55-limit) + the current row value
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use trigger, but I will not recommend using such as the best way to write triggers is not write triggers at all. You could create stored procedure and use it everywhere you need to insert rows in the tables and implement the logic there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it if you have SQL Server 2012 or later:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Id INT, ListItem INT);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (2, 20);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (3, 30);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (4, 40);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (6, 3);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (7, 10);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (8, 25);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (9, 15);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (10, 5);
WITH RunningTotal AS (
SELECT Id, ListItem, SUM(ListItem) OVER (ORDER BY Id) % 50 AS RT FROM @Table)
SELECT
    rt.Id,
    rt.ListItem,
    CASE WHEN rt.RT < rt2.RT THEN rt.RT + 50 ELSE rt.RT END AS RunningTotal
FROM
    RunningTotal rt
    LEFT JOIN RunningTotal rt2 ON rt2.Id = rt.Id - 1
ORDER BY
    rt.Id;
```

The tricky bit is allowing the numbers to overflow the 50 one time, otherwise this would be trivial.

Results are:

```
Id  LI  RunningTotal
1   10  10
2   20  30
3   30  60
4   40  50
5   2   2
6   3   5
7   10  15
8   25  40
9   15  55
10  5   10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table running_totals
(
    id  int identity(1,1),
    val int

)

insert into     running_totals

select 1    union all
select 20   union all
select 10   union all
select 30   union all
select 50   union all
select 10   union all
select 11   union all
select 22   union all
select 40   union all
select 60   union all
select 20   union all
select 10   union all
select 15

declare cur_run_tot cursor for select id,val from running_totals order by id asc
declare @id int ,@val int,@runtot int
open cur_run_tot
create table #RunTot
(
    id int,val int, runtot int
)

fetch next from cur_run_tot into @id,@val

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin 


    if @runtot is null or @runtot+@val > 50 
        set @runtot = @val
    else 
        set @runtot = @runtot+ @val

    insert into #RunTot
    select @id,@val,@runtot

    fetch next from cur_run_tot into @id,@val   
end

select id as ID, val as Current_Value, runtot as Running_Total from #RunTot

drop table #RunTot
deallocate cur_run_tot
```