# How to write SQL LAG query to get running Maximum of running total?

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate, lag

E.g. if the value that is being summed for the running total is sometimes negative, then the running total can go down.  But for each row, I also want the Max running total up to that point...

How would this code be augmented for that?

```
select ItemId, DateId, TargetRunningStock, 
       sum(TargetRunningStock) over (partition by itemid order by dateid)
from WarehouseData
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running total with maximum limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533015/running-total-with-maximum-limit)

Comment: No it's rather different

Comment: Where is your running total (in your query)?

Answer (score 0):

The question is, a bit, unclear, does the following come in the direction of what you try to do?  (If not please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76978110/edit) the question and improve it by sharing more info.

```
-- E.g. if the value that is being summed for the running total is sometimes negative, 
-- then the running total can go down. 
-- But for each row, I also want the Max running total up to that point...
SELECT 
  id,
  value,
  SUM(CASE WHEN value>0 THEN value ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER by id) as running_total
FROM test;
```

output:

| id | value | running_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | -4 | 3 |
| 4 | 8 | 11 |
| 5 | -16 | 11 |
| 6 | 32 | 43 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Tkv5XoMp)